# Read/Wrtite file in ASP.net when published with somee domain

Tags: c#

i have the problem that i need to access xml and xlxs file in a website code with asp.net. I have read and written well in local server but when i published to host. I can not access the folder in host server. Here is my code:

```
protected void CheckUsername(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<User> NewList = new List<User>();
            String _file = 
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APPData3"]; //C:/user.xml                                    
            if (!File.Exists(_file))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("No Data found");
            }
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<User>));
            using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(_file))
            {
                NewList = (List<User>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
            foreach (var item in NewList)
            {
                if (Username.Text.ToString() == 
           item.Username.ToString() && Password.Text.ToString() == 
            item.Password.ToString())
                {
                    checking = true;
                }
            }
            if (checking)
            {
                Session["username"] = Username.Text.ToString();
                Response.Redirect("EditTable.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Username.Text = "Sai thông tin";
            }
            
        }
```

So, how could i access the folder after published to host (somee). Please help.

Comment: Sorry, i just edit the post

Comment: Thank you. Is `APPData3` providing the correct file location?

Comment: this is local folder (C:/user.xml). The code working fine in my computer (IIS service) but when i upload to a global host (Somee.com) how could i access the folder in the host? I used (~/App_Data/user.xml) but it is error location

Comment: A web app having permissions to access the root of the C drive isn't a good idea anyway. Presumably this is a permissions issue. Solution: put the file somewhere the web application has access to.

Comment: thanks, but where could i put the file in?

Comment: I don't know. Presumably in a subdirectory of where the application code is.